# Batch script for automatic file swapping

Tags: java, xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tool in java that can convert values in xml files into 3d models (using transformation matrix with some textures).

To run it I'm using very simple batch script :

```
java.exe -cp path/to/tool.jar;path/to/3dlib.jar;path/to/textures.jar -Dsomejavaoptions -Dappdir=directory tool.some.mainclass file.xml file.bin
PAUSE
```

If I will place this `.bat` file in my `xml` folder it will do the job + eventually show in windows shell whats wrong (file not exist, wrong attributes, missing contents etc)

Typing filenames manually in .bat fie is good for about 10 files, but I have about 10000 to convert by this way.
all `.xml` files are in `xml` folder and file names are numeric from 1 to 10000.

How to make this process more automatic? I tried to call file.bat with parameters from shell but I think I need some work with arguments and also script which will execute other `.bat` file with parameters every 10000 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over files in directory

```
for /r %i in (*) do java.. %i
```

You can also use [forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx)

```
forfiles /s
```

And you can use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) with bash

```
for f in *.xml; do echo "Processing $f file.."; java.. $f; done
```